# How to remove numbered blank page before title page?

Tags: errors, blank-page

so I'm using TexShop in Mac OS X for a report but a blank page with nothing but two equals signs (==) appeared as page number 1 after I added the bibliography (I think, but I am not sure if this is the reason). The title page appears as my 2nd page in the document but is not numbered, the table of contents page that follows the title page also has the page numbering of 1.

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
some title
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

I would appreciate any reason as of why this happen and how to solve it.
Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are using a template you found online. There is no way you can put together so many obsolete packages by yourself. I would recommend not to use the template and read an introduction instead.

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct, the bibliography set-up is causing the problem.  You should not load the `natbib` and `apacite` packages at the same time.  Instead load `apacite` only, but with the `natbibapa` option:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
```

See the documentation of the `apacite` package, either via `texdoc apacite` on your system or at https://ctan.org/pkg/apacite?lang=en